# Are open affine sets a base for the topology of a scheme?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme. Then $X$ is covered by open affines $\operatorname{Spec} A_i$ for some rings $A_i$, by definition. But do those necessarily give a base for the topology of $X$? Is it true that finite intersections of affines are again affine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not necessarily true that a finite intersection of affine open subsets is affine.  However, they still are a basis for the topology, since that only requires that if $U\subseteq X$ is an open set and $x\in U$ then there is some affine open $V\subseteq U$ which contains $x$.  To prove this, pick an open affine $W\cong\operatorname{Spec} A$ that contains $x$.  Then $U\cap W$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $W$.  By definition of the topology on $\operatorname{Spec} A$, this means there exists some $f\in A$ such that the distinguished open set $D(f)$ satisfies $x\in D(f)\subseteq U\cap W$.  Since $D(f)\cong \operatorname{Spec} A_f$ is itself an affine open subscheme of $X$, we can take $V=D(f)$.

(Note that in general, for a collection of sets to form a basis for some topology, they do not have to be closed under finite intersections.  Instead, you only need any finite intersection of basis sets to be *covered* by basis sets.)

Comment: What you wrote seems like the property of defining a topology on a set given a collection of subsets. In the case of the OP, we already have a topology on $X$. So, we just need to show that every open subset of $X$ is a union of affine open subsets. This will tell us the set of all affine open subsets form a base.

Comment: @user46372819: Thanks!  I've corrected the answer.